# I would like to estimate the indirect effect of each mediator in a mediation analysis with multiple mediators using CMAverse

Tags: r, mediation

I wuold like to do a mediation analysis with exposure as A and outcome as Y (binary value). However, there are two mediators, M1 and M2 (both continuous values), and I wuold like to obtain an estimate of the indirect effect via M1, an estimate of the indirect effect via M2, and an estimate of the direct effect via neither. the CMAverse is a R package that can also consider multiple mediators, but there is only one type of direct and indirect effects obtained.  That is, I can get an estimate of the indirect effect via M1 or/and M2 and an estimate of the direct effect via neither.

Can I obtain estimates of indirect effects via M1, indirect effects via M2, and direct effects via neither in the CMAverse?